# Converting pandas Series to dictionary, using dict() vs to_dict(): what are the subtle differences?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Both works on Pandas Series objects producing similar output: creates a dictionary. But I noticed they are not interchangeable everywhere.

Comment: If you call `dict(a)` and `a.to_dict()`, you will see that the difference is not subtle at all but quite visible. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: Where are they not interchangeable?

Comment: @DYZ it actually is quite subtle for `pd.Series`, not so subtle for `pd.DataFrame`

Answer (score 5):

The main difference is that `to_dict` will map the values to built-in Python types:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: s = pd.Series([1,2,3],index=['a','b','c'])

In [3]: [(type(k),type(v)) for k,v in s.to_dict().items()]
Out[3]: [(str, int), (str, int), (str, int)]
```

Whereas `dict` will not:

```
In [5]: [(type(k),type(v)) for k,v in dict(s).items()]
Out[5]: [(str, numpy.int64), (str, numpy.int64), (str, numpy.int64)]
```

Note, the `dict` constructor works with `pd.Series` objects because series implement the mapping interface, they provide a `.keys` method:

```
In [6]: s.keys()
Out[6]: Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')
```

So the `dict` constructor naively treats it as a mapping. You just needs a `.keys` method and `__getitem__`, see:

```
In [8]: class MyMapping:
   ...:     def keys(self):
   ...:         return [47, 48, 49]
   ...:     def __getitem__(self, item):
   ...:         return chr(item)
   ...:

In [9]: dict(MyMapping())
Out[9]: {47: '/', 48: '0', 49: '1'}
```

So you can thinking of the `dict` constructor doing something like:

```
for key in mapping.keys():
    self[k] = mapping[k]
```

Note, the `dict` constructor accepts other forms as well, from `help(dict)`:

```
 |  dict(mapping) -> new dictionary initialized from a mapping object's
 |      (key, value) pairs
 |  dict(iterable) -> new dictionary initialized as if via:
 |      d = {}
 |      for k, v in iterable:
 |          d[k] = v
 |  dict(**kwargs) -> new dictionary initialized with the name=value pairs
 |      in the keyword argument list.  For example:  dict(one=1, two=2)
```